# In tensorflow seq2seq framework, How to train data of different bucket-size in one batch

Tags: tensorflow, buckets

I applied [queued reader](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#creating-threads-to-prefetch-using-queuerunner-objects) to tensorflow seq2seq to avoid reading the whole dataset into memory and process them all in advance. I didn't bucket the dataset into different bucket files first to ensure one bucket-size per batch for that will also take a lot of time. As a consequence, each batch of data from queue reader may contain sequences of different bucket-size, which lead to a failure to run the original seq2seq model (It assume that data in one batch is of the same bucket-size, and only chose one sub-graph depending on the bucket-size to execute)

**What i have tried:**

In the original implementation, sub-graphs, as many as buckets, are constructed to share the same parameters. The only difference between them is the times of computation that should be taken during it's RNN process. 
I changed the sub-graph to a conditional one, which, when the `switch` is True, will compute the `bucket_loss` of this bucket and add it to `loss_list` and when the `switch` is False, will do nothing and add `tf.constant(0.0)` to `loss_list`. Finally, I use `total_loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss_list)` to collect all the losses and constructed gradient graph on it.  Also, I feed a `switches_list` into model at every step. The size of `switches_list` is the same as that of buckets, and if there is any data of the ith bucket-size in this batch, the corresponding ith switch in `switches_list` will be True, otherwise False.

**The Problems encountered:**

1. when the backpropagation process went through the `tf.cond(...)`
   node, I was warned by `gradient.py` that some sparse tensors are
   transformed to dense one
2. when I tried to fetch the `total_loss` or `bucket_loss`, I was told:

> ```
> ValueError: Operation u'cond/model_with_one_buckets/sequence_loss/truediv' has been marked as not fetchable.
> ```

**Would you please help me:**

- How can I solve the two problems above?
- How should I modify the graph to meet my requirement?
- Any better ideas for training data of different bucket-size in one
  batch?
- Any better ideas for applying asynchronous queue reader to seq2seq
  framework without bucketing the whole dataset first?

Answer (score 0):

I would (did) throw out the bucketing entirely. Go with dynamic_rnn. Idea here is to fill up your batch with a padding symbol, as many as needed for THAT batch to arrive at equal length for all members of THAT batch (usually just the size of the longest member of the respective batch). Solves all four of your questions, but yes, it is some hassle to rewrite. (I dont regret it at all though)

I did many things that were very particular to my case and data on the way, thus sharing makes no sense, but maybe you want to check out this implementation: [Variable Sequence Lengths in TensorFlow](https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/)